# .Net Core Project won't open browser by default

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When debugging in VS 2019 the api url automatically opens which is different from the angular live url.

The angular live url is my actual complete application. Is there a way to open that url automatically when debugging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to modify your json config a little bit. So when you use VS to run your code or using dotnet run command you will use port 59709 to run your app

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59709/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "ancmHostingModel": "InProcess"
    },
    "KaddaTechnologies": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59709/"
    }
  }
}
```